# How to Add JTextField & JCheckBox to ArrayList Object

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcheckbox

I'm working on my very first GUI app.

I have an `ArrayList` of the Parent Class `Plant` of which I have four child classes.

I have some `JTextField`s with some information and some `JCheckBox`s with other information...

The `JTextField`s should be converted into `String`s and the `JCheckBox`s into `boolean`.

I need to add all of these components to an `ArrayList` and then display the list of the `Plant`s.

How can I do that?

Example:

```
public class Flower extends Plant{

   private boolean thorns;
   private boolean smell;   

   public Flower(String name, String id, String color, boolean blnThorns, boolean blnSmell){
      super(name, id, color);
      thorns = blnThorns;
      smell = blnSmell;

   }

   public boolean isThorns(){

      return thorns;
   }

   public void setThorns(boolean blnThorns){
      thorns = blnThorns;  
   }

   public boolean isSmell(){

      return smell;
   }

   public void setSmell(boolean blnSmell){
      smell = blnSmell;  
   }


}
```

This is my ArrayList

```
ArrayList<Plant> plantList = new ArrayList<Plant>();
```

Here I try to add the parameters for the Flower:

```
private void addFlower(ArrayList<Plant> plantList){

    //Adding window
    JFrame addingFrame = new JFrame();
    addingFrame.setTitle("Plant Database Interface");
    addingFrame.setSize(600, 200);
    addingFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    addingFrame.setVisible(true);

    //ADDING FRAME LAYOUT
    addingFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //TRAITS
    JPanel fields = new JPanel();
    addingFrame.add(fields, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");      
    JTextField  nameField = new JTextField(15);
    String name = nameField.getText();


    JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("ID:");      
    JTextField  idField  = new JTextField(10);
    String id = idField.getText();

    JLabel colorLabel = new JLabel("Color:");      
    JTextField  colorField = new JTextField(10);
    String color = colorField.getText();

    fields.add(nameLabel);
    fields.add(nameField);

    fields.add(idLabel);
    fields.add(idField);

    fields.add(colorLabel);
    fields.add(colorField);

    JPanel traits = new JPanel();
    addingFrame.add(traits , BorderLayout.CENTER );

    JCheckBox thornsBox = new JCheckBox("Thorns Present");
    thornsBox.setSelected(false);
    traits.add(thornsBox);

    JCheckBox smellBox = new JCheckBox("Smell Present");
    smellBox.setSelected(false);
    traits.add(smellBox);

    JPanel southPanel = new JPanel();
    addingFrame.add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton addPlantBtn = new JButton("Add Plant");
    southPanel.add(addPlantBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
    southPanel.add(cancelBtn, BorderLayout.WEST);

    boolean blnThorns;
    boolean blnSmell;

    //I REALLY DON'T KNOW HOW TO DO THIS PART
    thornsBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                blnThorns =true;
            }
            else{
                blnThorns = false;
            }
        }
    });

    smellBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
                blnSmell =true;
            }
            else{
                blnSmell = false;
            }
        }
    });               

    addPlantBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //plantList.add(new Flower(name, id, color, blnThorns, blnSmell)); //HOW TO DO????................
        }
    });


    cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            addingFrame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(addingFrame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Simply try `String jTextFieldValue = JTextField.getText();` and then add `jTextFieldValue` to your `ArrayList`

Comment: Yo Downvoter... this is a decent question.. please comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use your `addPlantBtn` `ActionListener` to gather the information you need when it's called

```
addPlantBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Flower flower = new Flower(nameField.getText(), idField.getText(), colorField.getText(), thornsBox.isSelected(), smellBox.isSelected());
        plantList.add(flower);
```

You would, also, find it easier, if you created a dedicated `JPanel`, designed to gather the user details and generate a `Flower` when you requested it to (from the values of the fields).  You could then use this panel on some kind of dialog when ever you needed it.

Have a look at [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more details

For example...

```
public class FlowerPane extends JPanel {

    JTextField nameField = new JTextField(15);
    JTextField idField = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField colorField = new JTextField(10);
    JCheckBox smellBox = new JCheckBox("Smell Present");
    JCheckBox thornsBox = new JCheckBox("Thorns Present");

    public FlowerPane() {
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("ID:");
        JLabel colorLabel = new JLabel("Color:");

        add(nameLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(idLabel, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(idLabel, gbc);

        gbc.gridx++;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        add(nameField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(idField, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(colorField, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        add(thornsBox, gbc);
        gbc.gridy++;
        add(smellBox, gbc);
    }

    public Flower create() {
        return new Flower(nameField.getText(), idField.getText(), colorField.getText(), thornsBox.isSelected(), smellBox.isSelected());
    }

}
```

Which you could then use by doing something like...

```
FlowerPane flowerPane = new FlowerPane();
switch (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, flowerPane, "Flower", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE)) {
    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
        Flower flower = flowerPane.create();
        plantList.add(flower);
        break;
}
```

Or add it to some other container

Comment: @d_PI Glad it could help